# Protoge / OWL make a property refer to another property

Tags: rdf, owl, protege

I want to create a Container class that contains Node objects. One of the properties I want the Container class to be able to express is `SequenceProperty`. This object property, I'd like to be able to act as a pointer to some expected property held by each Node associated with the container to be used to determine the order of sequencing of the Nodes in the Container.

I could create some special SequenceOrder property and have the Nodes use this themselves, but I wanted to allow this to be more open so that for some Containers I could reference `StartDate` as the `SequenceProperty` and in others, perhaps have a totally different property called `ListOrder` for example.

So when defining a specific type of Container, I want the modeller to be able to define the method by which the Sequence of Nodes can be determined.

Protégé doesn't seem to allow me to set the range of an ObjectProperty to be something that isn't another Class. But in my use-case, I don't want it to be. Is this something I would have to model outside of Protégé? And if so, would it be to simply add the relationships:

```
SequenceProperty 
    rdfs:domain Container;
    rdfs:range rdf:Property;
```

Or is there some rule or specification that forbids this, or is there a preferred way of modelling this kind of "meta" relationship? I had looked into the OWL specification's `rdf:Seq` and `rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty` which offers an alternative way of modelling this, but this seems an even more alien approach to that acceptable or modellable by Protégé. I don't know if that reveals my ignorance of Protégé, or if it's a deliberate design choice on Protégé's part.

Comment: Having rdf:Property as the range of a SequenceProperty is meaningless according to the [OWL 2 Direct Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/) which gives a precise mathematical set theoretic meaning to OWL.

Comment: You seem to come to OWL from a software engineering object oriented perspective. If this is indeed the case, you could create a UML class diagram of your design and translate it to OWL. See [my blog](https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/) where I give the translation from UML to OWL. Unfortunately you will need to do the translation by hand as there are no tools currently to do this. Or post it here and I can help.

Comment: What is your reason for using OWL? Usually when people use OWL, they are interested in reasoning on their ontology to obtain implicit inferences. But you made no mention of inferences you will like to see. Hence, my reason for asking.

Comment: For context, I am indeed coming from a software engineering perspective. I am building a set of software components which, if presented with data that conforms to a given data model as specified in a rich data-modelling language to support the functionality and structure I'm seeking to establish, will provide a robust yet flexible set of capabilities. 

A big portion  of those capabilities revolve around treating blocks of knowledge in graph form as sets of triples,  as such OWL would seem to be a natural modelling language to help define and document the data input specifications.

Comment: Later, yes, reasoning would come into the picture, and firming up aspects of the model such that it supports various active reasoning pathways will be important, but for now, I just want to establish some modelling groundwork to help set out the foundation on which later functionality will evolve. If I can publish the data specifications in terms of a set of OWL ontologies, that helps - and in that respect, I'm adopting OWL as a tool for delivering data format specifications, in the same way (though more flexibly and with additional logic) that you might publish a json schema or csv format.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll share more details as I progress, and will look over your blog with great interest.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as [*punning*](https://www.w3.org/2007/OWL/wiki/Punning), or what OWL calls [*metamodeling*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Metamodeling). Such a thing is allowed in RDF, RDFS, and OWL (except for DL and Lite), so, as far as I can tell, this might be a limitation of Protégé, since `rdf:Property` is metamodeled as a class and thus valid as `rdfs:range`. Perhaps it treats it as a special vocabulary item, more like a special piece of "syntax" outside the universe describable by OWL rather than something to be reasoned about. Nevertheless, it is valid, and there are similar properties in existence, such as [`foaf:membershipClass`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/#term_membershipClass).

Note however that while OWL itself may allow you to treat a property as an individual this way, there is nothing that would allow you to cross this gap during reasoning, for example the fact that a specific property is a `SequenceProperty` of a container will not entail anything about the actual property expansion, i.e. which individuals are linked by the property.